# Crear un objeto cuyas propiedades sean las letras de una frase y los valores sean las veces que esa letra se repite con javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, objeto

Necesito crear un objeto en el que las keys sean las letras y los values las veces que se repiten. Si la letra ya se ha encontrado, no debe repetirse...

He conseguido hacerlo pero me ocurren dos cosas... la primera es que a la hora de quitar los espacios en blanco, me gustaría hacerlo con trim(), pero no sé por qué no me funciona, me devuelve la frase igual, por eso he tenido que hacer la comprobación dentro del primer bucle.

La segunda cosa que me pasa es que siento que esto se puede optimizar, me parece que tener que usar dos bucles es demasiado para un ejercicio así... El primer bucle me crea un objeto con las letras como keys y todos los valores a null, y así como puedo asignarle los nuevos valores en e segundo bucle...

¿Alguien sabría decirme como mejorar esto o si es esta la mejor forma de hacerlo?

```
let frase= "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Curabitur eget bibendums"

    let counts = {};
    
    let fraseSplit = frase.toLowerCase().split("")
    
    for (let i = 0; i < fraseSplit .length; i++) {
        if (fraseSplit [i] !== " " ){
            counts[fraseSplit [i]] = null;
        }
    }
    
      for (let char of fraseSplit ) {
        if (Object.keys(counts).includes(char)) {
          counts[char] += 1
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente puedes reducir tu código a un solo ciclo utilizando regex para eliminar los espacios en blancos: `replace(/\s+/g, "")`.

El método de string `replace()` toma dos argumentos, el primero es el patrón que va a remplazar y el segundo es el texto que utilizará para remplazar la coincidencia. En tu caso el patrón es uno o más espacios en blanco `\s+` y los se quieren eliminar, por eso se remplazan por una cadena vacía `""`. `g` es un identificador global que indica que se remplacen todas las coincidencias, de lo contrario remplazaría solo la primera.

No necesitas crear el objeto con todas las letras presentes antes de contarlas, puedes hacer ambas cosas juntas. Por cada letra preguntas si ya existe. Si existe, la incrementas, y si no existe, la creas en ese preciso momento con valor 1.

Por lo demás, tu código está perfecto, y ya es cuestión de si prefieres un ciclo `for` o un `reduce` o simplemente un ternario en lugar de un `if`. La complejidad será la misma `O(n)` donde n es la longitud de la cadena sin espacios.

Con `for` quedaría:

```js
let frase = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Curabitur eget bibendums"

let fraseSplit = frase.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, "")
    .split("");

let count = {};
for (let i = 0; i < fraseSplit.length; i++) {
    let char = fraseSplit[i];
    count.hasOwnProperty(char) ? count[char]++ : count[char] = 1;
}

console.log(count);
```

Si quieres expresarlo de una manera más funcional con un `reduce`, puedes intentar algo como:

```js
let frase = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Curabitur eget bibendums"

let count = frase.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, "")
    .split("")
    .reduce((c, char) => {
        c.hasOwnProperty(char) ? c[char]++ : c[char] = 1
        return c
    }, {});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Jaime muchísimas gracias. La explicación es de 10!!!